# How to fix case-control matching with SPSS fuzzy command

Tags: matching, spss, fuzzy

I am trying to create a 1:4 case-control match in my data, but the final dataset does not incldue any controls. Why is it?

I am using SPSS 23 with 745,414 observations, 595,388 controls and 150026 cases (20.1% a 1:4 ratio). The cases and controls are already matched for age and sex, but I am trying to create clusters of five observations (1 case and 4 controls), each marked with a specific ID.

This is the code I've been using:

FUZZY BY=age sex supplierid=supplier 
newdemanderidvar=sid group=case

%%sex ranges from 8-88m age can take two values (1 or 2), "supplier" is a serial number from 1 to 745,414 and "case" marks whether the observation is a case (1) or control (0).%%

I also tried seperating the file to control and cases datasets, and uses a slightly different code:

I expected the results to be as in the following example:

[image]

But instead the controls are simply excluded from the new ID variable:

[image]
Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your FUZZY command looks incomplete.  A lot can often be gleaned from what the program will do on it's own.  Try the "Data -> Case Control Matching..." menus to setup your analysis and see how different the pasted command syntax is from yours

Yours:

```
FUZZY BY=age sex supplierid=supplier newdemanderidvar=sid group=case
```

Pasted by the UI:

```
FUZZY BY=age sex SUPPLIERID=supplier NEWDEMANDERIDVARS=sid GROUP=case EXACTPRIORITY=FALSE MATCHGROUPVAR=id 
 /OPTIONS SAMPLEWITHREPLACEMENT=FALSE MINIMIZEMEMORY=TRUE SHUFFLE=FALSE.
```

Granted, there are defaults to the above command, but the UI wonlt let you out of it until you've specified the minimum values to make the job run.

Here is my example syntax to create a dataset like I think you are describing, and run FUZZY against it.

```
* Encoding: UTF-8. 

DATASET CLOSE ALL.
NEW FILE.
OUTPUT CLOSE ALL.

INPUT PROGRAM. 
LOOP supplier = 1 TO 745414. 
COMPUTE case =  (mod($CASENUM,4)=0). 
COMPUTE age = SUM(TRUNC(UNIFORM(80)),8). 
COMPUTE sex = SUM(TRUNC(UNIFORM(2)),1). 
END CASE. 
END LOOP. 
END FILE. 
END INPUT PROGRAM. 
VALUE LABELS case 0 'Control' 1 'Case'/ 
     sex 1 'Female' 2 'Male'. 
EXECUTE. 
** A 1:4 ratio *.
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES =case.

** Your posted command -- fails for me **.
*FUZZY BY=age sex supplierid=supplier newdemanderidvar=sid group=case.
** The command the UI built and pasted **.
FUZZY BY=age sex SUPPLIERID=supplier NEWDEMANDERIDVARS=sid GROUP=case EXACTPRIORITY=FALSE  MATCHGROUPVAR=id 
/OPTIONS SAMPLEWITHREPLACEMENT=FALSE MINIMIZEMEMORY=TRUE SHUFFLE=FALSE.
```